# How to convert distort perspecitve leads to "@ fatal/mogrify.c/MogrifyImage/1423"

Tags: imagemagick-convert

I have to distort some pictures in the perspective way with Imagemagick. One of the four given points in the pictures stay in the same position and the other 3 points should distort around the first point.

In my last researches I only found a solution for the output `"convert: Memory allocation failed 'name.jpg'"`. So I changed the the memory value in my `policy.xml` to the value of my whole RAM.

If I write

```
convert building.jpg -matte -virtual-pixel transparent \ 
-distort Perspective \ 
'4,126 4,126  7,39 4,39  85,0 100,39  86,127 100,126' \ 
building_pers.png
```

in the console (given by my professor), I get the output in the heading.

Now I don't know, what I should do. I hope you can help me.

P.S.: I have some difficulties with English, so I hope you can forgive my possible mistakes. Please answer in a way easy to understand.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not know what the question is. Did you get an output? Look for it in the current working directory. Did you get a further error message? What version of Imagemagick, what is the date of the version and what is the platform?  Your code looks fine for an Imagemagick 6 version, if you have ordered the points correctly. If your Imagemagick version is too old, the ordering would have been inpt1 inpt2 inpt3 inpt4 outpt1 outpt2 outpt3 outpt4. Current versions use inpt1 outpt1  inpt2 outpt2  inpt3 outpt3  inpt4 outpt4.

Comment: Sorry, I work the first time with ImageMagick and don't know what you need to can answer. 
The question is what I have to do that the distort command is working. I get the output 
"convert: Memory allocation failed 'name.jpg' @ fatal/mogrify.c/MogrifyImage/1423" 

and the pictures are not distorted. I have the ImageMagick version 7.0.8-Q16 an my platform is Windows 10 (version 1809). I don't find the date of the ImageMagick version but I installed it 2 or 3 days ago. 

Thank you for your hint

Answer (score 0):

With Imagemagick 7, you must change "convert" to "magick". Try that. Also does your Imagemagick version list jpg for a delegate?  Check by `magick -version` and report all that is returned.  How big is your image? Remove -matte. That was deprecated in Imagemagick 7. It should not be needed in your command. Your code is Unix syntax and not for plain Windows.

Try removing all \ and make one long command line as follows in a normal Window terminal. If you are in a Windows Unix terminal, you would have had to install a Unix version of Imagemagick.

So in normal Windows, try

```
magick.exe building.jpg -virtual-pixel transparent -distort Perspective '4,126 4,126  7,39 4,39  85,0 100,39  86,127 100,126' building_pers.png
```

Comment: If I type "magick -version" I get at Delegates: 
"bzlib cairo flif freetype gslib heic jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr lzma openexr pangocairo png ps raw rsvg tiff webp xml zlib"
So do I have to work for example with png-images instead of jpg-images? 
The image is 146x150 big with  8 KB, but this is only a test image. Does it work with images they are 4000x3000 big with ca. 3 MB?
I use normal Windows and tried your code but I get the output
"magick.exe: invalid list of numbers '-distort' ''4,126' at CLI arg 4 @ error/operation.c/CLISimpleOperatorImage/2231"

Comment: Your list of delegates does not show jpg. So you cannot work with JPG image unless you install that delegate? How did you install it - binary or source code? Where did it come from? If from Imagemagick, then there may be a bug in the binary. It should have come with jpg. What do you get when you do `magick.exe -list format`? Look for the line starting with JPG or JPEG and look at the end of the line. It should say something about the jpg library version number. If there is no entry for JPG or JPEG or no library (such as libjpeg) listed, then your install was bad or the binary was bad.

Comment: I install it binary from Imagemagick. For "magick.exe -list format" I get in the JPG-line "Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format (libjpeg-turbo 2.0.2)". I testet the convert command to convert a jpg-image to a png-image and it works. And when I tried the distort command with a png-image I get the same output like the distort command with jpg-image. Should I try to install it again by source code?

Comment: See my comment about the coordinate list order. Post a link to your image and I will try to use your command. How big is it. If too large, then you could be running out of RAM or the Imagemagick resources are set too low. What do you get from  `magick -list resource`?  Did you use my version of your command using magick not convert and removing -matte?

Comment: The link to the image:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tJGJuU228A-NeEqN_p86SkQ_vx7wRLYO/view?usp=sharing
The image has 8 KB and is 146x150 pixel big, I have 16 GB RAM, changed in the policy.xml the value for RAM to this 16 GB. I tried your version of command with magick instead of convert and without -matte but I get the output "magick.exe: invalid list of numbers '-distort' (...)" like last time. The output for "magick -list resource" is "Resource limits: Width: 214.748MP, Height: 214.748MP, (...), Memory: 3.98463GiB, (...), File: 1536 (...)".

Comment: This command works fine for me on IM 7.0.8.56 Q16 Mac OSX. Note on unix-like systems there is no .exe. `magick building.jpg -virtual-pixel transparent -distort Perspective '4,126 4,126  7,39 4,39  85,0 100,39  86,127 100,126' building_pers.png`. On Windows you may need to change single quotes to double quotes. Try that.

Comment: That was the problem. With double quotes it works.
Thank you very very much.

Comment: Exactly as you said, @fmw42, if you find the time, would you expand your helpful comment to an answer?